# Why am i getting the error that "System (2).py", line 14, in <module> BottomFrame(side = BOTTOM) TypeError: 'Frame' object is not callable"

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk
import random
import datetime

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
root.title ("Stock Control System")

TopFrame = Frame(root, width = 1350, height = 100, bd = 14, relief = 'raise')
TopFrame.pack(side = TOP)

BottomFrame = Frame(root, width = 1350, height  = 200, bd = 20, relief = 'raise')
BottomFrame(side = BOTTOM)

LeftMidFrame = Frame(BottomFrame, width = 600, height = 1000, bd = 14, relief = 'raise')
LeftMidFrame(side = LEFT)

RightMidFrame = Frame(root, width = 750, height = 1000, bd = 14, relief = 'raise')
RightMidFrame(side=RIGHT)

lblTitle = Label(TopFrame, font('arial',40,'bold'), text = "Stock Control System", bd = 10, width = 41, justify = 'center')
lblTitle.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

Why am I getting the error that "Frame" is not callable? This is supposed to be a stock management system but for some reason it is not working...

Answer (score 1):

This is because instances of `Frame` are objects and not functions. Hence, they are not callable. You need to call `.pack` on each `Frame` instance, just like you did for `TopFrame`. For example:

```
BottomFrame = Frame(root, width = 1350, height  = 200, bd = 20, relief = 'raise')
BottomFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM)
```

Furthermore, there is an `=` missing in the second to last line. It must read

```
lblTitle = Label(TopFrame, font=('arial',40,'bold'), text = "Stock Control System", bd = 10, width = 41, justify = 'center')
```

Comment: btnTotal = Button(RightMidFrame, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="Total", bd =6, width=15, command = Product)
    btnTotal(row=10,column=0)
    lblExit = Button(RightMidFrame, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="Exit", bd = 6, width=15, command = iExit)
    lblExit.grid(row=10,column=1)
    lblReset = Button(RightMidFrame, font=('arial',12,'bold'), text ="Reset", bd = 6, width=15, command = Reset)
    lblReset.grid(row=10,column=2)

Comment: for the above code it says Button is not callable. Do you know why?